# sed replace a word and it's previous word seperated by delimeter

Tags: sed

I have a file and in it there are many occurances of `*.client` which i wanna replace with `tbot` like ~

```
await event.client.send_file(bla bla)
await master.client.send_message(bla bla)
await iter.client.get_entity(bla bla)
```

and i wanna replace them like ~

```
await tbot.send_file(bla bla)
await tbot.send_message(bla bla)
await tbot.get_entity(bla bla)
```

I tried something like `sed -i 's/*.client/tbot/g' thefile` but didn't work, any solutions ?

Comment: ok i edited the question with my attempt

Comment: Restoring original tags used by @MissAlexaRobot as question is seeking regex help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/[^[:blank:]]+\.client/tbot/' thefile
```

```
await tbot.send_file(bla bla)
await tbot.send_message(bla bla)
await tbot.get_entity(bla bla)
```

To save changes inline use:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/[^[:blank:]]+\.client/tbot/' thefile
```

**Regex Details:**

- `[^[:blank:]]+`: Match 1+ of any non-whitespace character
- `\.client`: Match test `.client`